# Invalid command 'auth_basic'

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication

I recently added this to a htaccess file:

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
AuthName "Authorization Required"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

now I get the error
'.htaccess: Invalid command 'auth_basic', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration'

Does this mean my host doesnt have basic authentication turned on??

-Edit I have just checked using apache2ctl -M and auth_basic_module DOES appear in the list

Comment: are you *sure* there isn't a "auth_basic" somewhere in your htaccess file?

Comment: Hi sorry about delay, but no, there isnt, the rest of the file contains rewrite access rules and thats it!